# Settings icon functionality with knockoutJS

Tags: knockout.js

I am working on a sample where I have a settings image named "lnksetting" and upon clicking it, its showing up a div named "settingsDiv" with few list items (1. mute 2. about me 3. more options).

Now I am trying to figure out a way to hide "settingsDiv" div when moving focus out of lnksetting

I added a event mouseout to databind of knockoutJS and made changes to set observable to true/false ( this observable is set to settingsDiv )

But If I do this, even when trying to select an option from settingsDiv, as I am moving focus out of lnksetting, it is setting visibility false to settingsDiv.

Can someone suggest some idea on I can achieve hiding of settingsDiv when mouseOut of lnksetting and also allow selection of options from settingsDiv

Below is the pseudo code that I am using for this.

```
<img id="lnksetting"  alt="setting" src="settings.png" data-bind="click: ChatSettingClick , event: { mouseout: ChatSettingHideHover } ">
```

The div that I am showing up on clicking lnksetting is

```
 <!-- ko if: ShowChatSettingOptions -->
<div class="settingsDiv">        
    <ul>            
        <li>mute</li>   
        <li>about me</li> 
        <li>more options</li>
    </ul>    
</div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

and In ChatSettingClick, I am setting ShowChatSettingOptions to true/false as below

```
self.ChatSettingClick= function () {
self.ShowChatSettingOptions(!self.ShowChatSettingOptions());
}
```

Comment: Can you post the minumum code required in jsfiddle?

Comment: you can have one-thing working at one instance not both . To me doesn't make sense why you need something like this .

Comment: I would recommend *not* to bind vital page functionality to mouse movements. That makes for a *really* crappy UX in general and it's even impossible to use on touch screens or for people who can not use a mouse for some reason.

Comment: i gave it a try check this http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/LkqTU/24499/ as possible alternative  . cheers .

Comment: @Super cool thanks for the fiddle. It a bit different to what I need. My issue was, I need to persist settingsDiv when I click on lnksetting and also when I hover on it and it should be hidden when I am not hovering on settingsDiv or when I didnt click lnksetting

Comment: @Tomalak, I agree it. but if suppose am not targetting for touch screens or the other case.. how can I think of an alternative to do this?

Comment: You need to keep two observables, one `forceShow` that reacts (toggles) only on *click*, and one `hoverShow` that only reacts to *mouseenter* and *mouseleave*. Then use `visible: forceShow() || hoverShow()` to control div visibility.

Comment: "one hoverShow that only reacts to mouseenter and mouseleave" mouseenter/mouseleave for?
I think we would not have settingsDiv rendered at all to check for mouseenter trigger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per @Tomalak's comments, stopped concentrating on mouse moments as its impossible to use on touch screens.